# Linux `mount --bind` made client's folder disappear?

Tags: linux, mount, bind, vsftpd

I tried making a VSFTPD user with access to all of our clients' FTP folders. (the users are all chroot'ed to their home directories, where the public_html folders are).

What I did was create a new FTP user and created a client directory inside `/home/global_user/`. Then I used the following command to mount the client's user directory into the global user directory, like this:

```
mount --bind /home/global_user/client_directory /home/client/
```

What happened next is that indeed the folder was mounted, but all the files in the original folder are **gone**! They don't appear in the new mount either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> mount --bind olddir newdir

So after running

```
mount --bind /home/global_user/client_directory /home/client/
```

the original contents (none) of `/home/global_user/client_directory` are also available in `/home/client/`. You can't see the original contents of `/home/client` because you overlayed your new empty directory on top!

Just `umount` this, and try again with the arguments reversed.

Comment: Thank for your reply my friend. I tried to umount both folders, and I get "device is busy" for both directories, even when sudoing it.

Comment: That means some process is touching the mount target (`/home/client`) - make sure no shell is in there and try again (`lsof +D /home/client` may help).  Oh, and you're only trying to `umount /home/client`.

Comment: I figured it out - umount -l /home/client/ did the trick :)

Thank you for your help.